# Python writing text files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So, This is what I what i'm trying to do..

```
error = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberNameError"]""")
if error.is_displayed():
    print(line.strip() + " is taken")
else:
    print(line.strip() + " is available")
with open("emails_available.txt", "a") as email_txt:
    email_txt.write(line.strip() + "@hormail.com" + "\n")
```

How do I make it ONLY if the email is available then write into txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about placing the if/else inside the with?

```
error = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberNameError"]""")
with open("emails_available.txt", "a") as email_txt:
   if error.is_displayed():
      print(line.strip() + " is taken")
   else:
      print(line.strip() + " is available")
      email_txt.write(line.strip() + "@hormail.com" + "\n")
```

I assume there's probably a loop here somewhere that you did not include...that could go inside the `with` statement also.